# Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url lighthouse

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Yeah I've pretty much given up on fixing this error:
Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url.

When you view my site [www.mlamannadev.com](https://www.mlamannadev.com/) from an android device a banner does pop up so I don't know why I'm still getting this error in lighthouse, any thoughts?

Comment: That sounds like it's due to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/2576. It would be best to follow-up there.

Comment: Ill check it out, thanks!